# mango template to receive the callback after auto expire of document

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have a collection like below, which has expire-time set like below as part of schema .

```
db.createCollection(
          "userDetails", 
          {
    capped: false,
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["userId","userName"],
            properties: {
                userId: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be a string and is required"
                },
                userName: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "must be a string and match the regular expression pattern"
                },

            }
        }
    },
    validationLevel: "strict",
    validationAction: "error"
}          
);
db.userDetails.createIndex( { "userName": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds:6000});
```

So now whenever it expires it is getting delete from the mongodb, but I have some other requirement where I have to notify some other service about this deletion so I tried below code but this will I have execute every time, also I am not getting any records.

```
  template.execute("userDetails", new CollectionCallbackBoolean>() {
  public Boolean doInCollection(userDetails.class, DBCollection collection) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
    List<Document> indexes = collection.getIndexInfo();
    for (Document document : indexes) {
      log.info("Docouments " + document.get("userName")) 
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

So how to register to mongo for a callback to get these expired records using mongotemplate..